# HTML weird hyperlink not working

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have my Joomla website, and in an article i have this code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>

<div id="mmm" style="position: absolute; padding-top: 85px; padding-left: 455px;">{loadposition google_mapa}</div>
<hr />
<h4 style="padding-left: 60px; color: #99cc33; text-align: left;">Contactos:       </h4>
<hr />

<p class="MsoNormal" style="padding-left: 60px; text-align: justify;">
<span style="font-family: Century, serif;"><br /><img src="images/fb.png" border="0" width="25" height="25" style="border: 0; vertical-align: middle;" />
</span></p>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
```

My problem is, the first hyperlink is the same as the second, but the first work and the second don't. Any help would be appreciated,

John

EDIT: SORRY. I Accidentally copied the `<p>` inside the href. It isnt working

EDIT2: When i mean not working, it means it is not 'clickable', it looks like hyperlink but when i click nothing happens

EDIT3: The problem is in here:

```
<div id="mmm" style="position: absolute; padding-top: 85px; padding-left: 455px;">
<p> </p>
<p>{loadposition google_mapa}</p>
</div>
```

If i take out this, the links work. no idea why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a closing p tag in your link...

Facebook

Comment: sorry. i copied it wrong. check now. I'm telling you is exactly the same, first one works second not

Comment: It is not working because of this...{loadposition google_mapa} so when you will be online and that call will be interpreted all the link after it should work.

Comment: Yes, must be `{loadposition google_mapa}` as nothing seems wrong with the HTML, and it works. Maybe show us the code after publishing the article?

Comment: Can you show us the same snippet of code but after publishing? Something might be messing up your HTML structure in that `{loadposition google_mapa}`.

Comment: I'm sorry, what I meant was the code that is generated in the published article, and not in the back-office. Visit the article (like one of your site visitors) and shows us the HTML. As an alternative you can give us the URL and we'll see for ourselves :)

Comment: Once the {loadposition google_mapa} will be interprated and replace by the html content it represent the link under it should work.

Comment: It's definitely the map and the attribute `position: absolute` in the CSS. Can't you try and restructure the HTML so that you don't have to use the absolute positioning?

Comment: i don't know. i used absolute because i had an hard time trying to get the map to the right place. As i didn't got it to work, i used absolute and it is now exactly where i want it. idk ..

Comment: Maybe you could use two divs beside one another using `float: left`, like shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/2JCC3/1/

Answer (score 4):

You should take the `</p>` tag out of the `href` attribute for the URL to work.

EDIT:

The map div, loaded here:

```
<div id="mmm" style="position: absolute; padding-top: 85px; padding-left: 455px;">{loadposition google_mapa}</div>
```

is somehow affecting the links on the left, mainly because of the CSS property `position: absolute`.

As an alternative, you can try using two div's beside each other like showed [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JCC3/1/).

```
<div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px; border: solid 1px">
    <p>Facebook</p>
    <p>Address</p>
    <p>Email</p>
</div>
<div style="float: left; border: solid 1px">
    Map
</div>
```

Comment: sorry. i copied it wrong. check now. I'm telling you is exactly the same, first one works second not

Comment: @recoInrelax I edited my answer to include the solution proposed in the comments. It's a bit more detailed here, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The first hyperlink is not the same as the second one. The second one has a `</p>` in the href attribute, and `</p>http://www.google.com` is not a valid url.

Change the second one to:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: sorry. i copied it wrong. check now. I'm telling you is exactly the same, first one works second not

Answer (score 0):

not same.. you need to remove `</p>` tag from second one.